# Is there a way to retrieve the ADTs? It doesn't seem like using DDMTemplateLocalServiceUtil is the way to go

Tags: java, liferay, liferay-7

I'm trying to get all the adts of a website knowing it's groupid. However, it seems like the adts are mixed up with all the other templates of the site in the DDMTemplate table in the Database.

Comment: please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/364505

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DDMTemplates are a general portal concept to manage templates for different types of portal assets (not only ADTs). `DDMTemplateLocalService` is a service to use to also list the ADTs for a certain asset type. You need to first fetch your ClassNameId for the desired asset type to render. For example:

`com.liferay.portal.kernel.service.ClassNameLocalService.getClassNameId(AssetEntry.class)`

for AssetPublisher entries (or BlogsEntry and so on - for all other types of interest).
Having this id, you can query the ADTs of a site (groupId) using:

`com.liferay.dynamic.data.mapping.service.DDMTemplateLocalService.getTemplates(long groupId, long classNameId)`

Instead of using the *LocalServiceUtil static functions, you could also inject the service using the `@Reference` annotation. For example `@Reference private DDMTemplateLocalService ddmTemplateService;`.